# How to use shellTile in windows phone 8.1 run time Application

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

In the code below ShellTile is working in WP8.0, but when using WP8.1, it is not showing ShellTile.

What is the alternative to use ShellTile in WP8.1 Universal Apps?

```
ShellTile shellTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(tile => tile.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains(partOfUri));
```

Answer (score 0):

ShellTile is only available for Silverlight Apps. In Universal Apps you have to use ToastNotificationManager.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498187/display-local-toast-notification) for examples.

Comment: NavigationUri does no longer exist in UniversalApps (as you navigate by type and not an Uri). You have to use the **Launch** parameter in the tile Xml and handle the navigation in your **App.OnLaunched** overload.